# Cerrar sesion en hibernate al retornar un ArrayList

Tags: java, html, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

tengo un problema al querer cerrar una sesion en hibernate.
Les adjunto el código que me funciona

```
public ArrayList<Empresa> getEmpresas() {

    Session session = null;

    SessionFactory sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    session = sesion.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Query q = session.createQuery("from Empresa where estado_id=1");

    List<Empresa> lista = q.list();

    return (ArrayList) lista;

}
```

todo bien hasta ahí, el problema es que la sesión está quedando abierta y después de unos cuantos listados se me cae y me dice `too_many_connection` debido a que abre, abre y abre y no cierra nunca.
Ahora bien, si pongo `session.close();` me arroja un error de hibernate, adjunto Error:

> mensaje org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session.

Si me pudiesen orientar un poco quedaría muy agradecido.

PD: Estoy trabajando con MySQL e Hibernate

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() en lugar de openSession()? No necesitas abrir una nueva conexión o sesión cada vez, son reutilizables. Intenta aprender cómo funciona el pool de conexiones de Hibernate

Comment: Pon el código de Empresa.

Answer (score 0):

En mis ejercicios de Hibernate de clase, simplemente añadimos el siguiente código al final del método (antes del return).

```
    tx.commit();
```

Aunque para esas funciones en las cuales quieres obtener datos, te recomiendo que emplees la siguiente estructura.

```
public static Vector <Peregrino> listaPeregrinos (Session sesion) {
        Vector <Peregrino> vPeregrinos = new Vector <Peregrino> ();
        String orden = "from Peregrino order by dni";
        Query consulta = sesion.createQuery(orden);
        Iterator<Peregrino> it = consulta.iterate();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            vPeregrinos.add(it.next());
        }

        return vPeregrinos;
    }
```